# Convert an String to a Vector

Tags: java, vector

I have an `String[]` like `"[John, 12, 18, Home, Black]"`. How may I convert it to a vector in the easiest way?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this ?

```
Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>(Arrays.asList(yourStringArray)); // for list
```

for simple array :

```
Vector v = new Vector( Arrays.asList(array) );
```

as per your example :

```
String[] arr = { "John", "12", "18", "Home", "Black" };
Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

Comment: No. It did not work. I had an statement like [John, 12, 18, Home, Black] in a file which I read it from the file and stored in an string, now I want to convert it to a vector. When I use your first solution it shows me [[John, 12, 18, Home, Black]] which is a vector with 1 size. But the size should be 5, within 5 elements.

Comment: Then You will have to manipulate string came from file using `StringTokenizer` to separate the string. Or you can manually code for separate this strings.

Comment: may be you need to split you string into an array of tokens, by doing String arr[] = yourString.split(",") and then Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>(Arrays.asList(arr));

Comment: If solved then accept the answer so other don't visit and check for you solved question. Keep Smiling.. :)